# How to change copy/paste shortcut on linux system (GNOME)

Tags: linux, gnome

I would like to change shortcuts of copy, past, cut, etc.. on kali linux. Trying to set it more like OSX.

I found some shortcut options in settings and by command "gsettings" in terminal. But these copy/past commands are nowhere.

Where are they stored? How can i change them?

I tried xmodmap, but its not the answer. Because I don't need to remap keys. I just want to change shortcut of some commands.

**P.S.** swap keys is better choice but then i get another problem.
How do i change ^ singnal in terminal from ctrl to alt.

Comment: If your question would be closed here, I suggest to check also https://unix.stackexchange.com , where it would be likely on-topic.